# Why can't the class DetailsViewModel be instanced automatically when Hilt is used?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

It seems that the project use Hilt to generate object automatically.

The `class DetailsViewModel` is the child class of `ViewModel()`, I think the paramater  `viewModel: DetailsViewModel` in `fun DetailsScreen()` can be instanced automatically, but in fact it's assigned with `viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()`, why?

```
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()  
) {
    val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true)) {
        val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
        value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
            DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
        } else {
            DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
        }
    }

    when {
        uiState.cityDetails != null -> {
            DetailsContent(uiState.cityDetails!!, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        uiState.isLoading -> {
            Box(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        }
        else -> { onErrorLoading() }
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cityName = savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ARG_DETAILS_CITY_NAME)!!

    val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Hilt, you should use `hiltViewModel()` instead of `viewModel()`: it creates an object with all injections or returns an object already created in the current scope.

Compose is not part of Hilt, so I don't know how you expect this object to be created without any call? `hiltViewModel()` is already very short and does all the work for you.

Passing the view model as a default argument is made for the convenience of testing and using `@Preview`: in the main application you do not pass this argument and let the default `viewModel()`/`hiltViewModel()` be called, but in a test call you can pass a simulated view model.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that `Compose` doesn't support `hiltViewModel()` ? So the author had to use `viewModel()` intead of  `hiltViewModel()`  in the `Compose`.

Comment: @HelloCW I don't know why `hiltViewModel()` wasn't used, maybe it didn't exist yet when this project was created. But you should use it according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt)

Comment: Hi @HelloCW, did my answer solved your question? If so please accept it.